# Object storage system

Tags: object, storage

what is the basic requirement of object storage system .  is there any minimum set of interfaces  that must be exposed by object storage system.Are all vendor exposing same interfaces

Answer (score 0):

**Are you willing to develop your own object storage system?**

Object storage is a term which in turn used for the approach for storing, addressing, manipulating and managing as a single storage unit called objects.
There are many object storage system like **Amazon-S3**, **Openstack-SWIFT** etc.
They all have same kind of specifications but implementation is different.

There are some standard specifications also by **SNIA** called **[Cloud Data Management Interface (CDMI)](http://www.snia.org/cdmi)** which has been declared as an ISO standard for the Cloud Storage Systems.

Following is the link for more info [How-to guide: Object storage system implementation](http://searchcloudstorage.techtarget.com/guides/What-you-need-to-know-before-implementing-an-object-storage-system)